# mysql concat remove trailing dash if it exists

Tags: mysql

I have a select that concats several columns together separating them with a dash "-" character.  The last column 'description' may or may not have a value.  If it does, all is good, if it doesn't, I end up with a "-" at the end.  How can I get rid of the last character only if it is a "-"?

```
SELECT CONCAT(locationid,'-',city,'-',state,'-',country,'-',description) FROM sys_locations ORDER BY locationid
```

Example with 'description' column populated:
AUC01-Aurora-CO-US-DC

Example with 'description' column empty:
AUM01-Auburn Hills-MI-US-     <- notice trailing dash.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

You need [`NULLIF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', locationid, city, state, country, NULLIF(description, '')) 
FROM sys_locations ORDER BY locationid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(locationid,'-',city,'-',state,'-',country,IF(description is null,'',concat('-', description))) FROM sys_locations ORDER BY locationid
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle both NULL and '', try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(locationid,'-', city, '-', state, '-', country, case when description IS NULL or description = '' then '' else '-' end, description)
FROM sys_locations ORDER BY locationid
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.